# Django form doesn't take request.POST values

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a problem with my project. When i click on the submit button of the form i can see the correct data in request.POST (debug mode), but the function "form.is_valid" return an error. Infact if i skip the function e write only form.save it will raise "NOT NULL constraint failed: fatture_viaggio.distanza_km".

Here is my code:

```
def clienti(request):
    clienti_list = Cliente.objects.all().order_by('nome').exclude(nome='Inalca')
    viaggi_list = Viaggio.objects.all().order_by('-data_viaggio')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'Aggiungi_Cliente' in request.POST:
            formC = ClienteForm(request.POST)
            if formC.is_valid():
                nuovo_cliente = formC.save()
            return redirect('clienti')
        formV = ViaggioForm(request.POST)
        #if formV.is_valid():
        nuovo_viaggio = formV.save()
        return redirect('clienti')
    else:
        formC = ClienteForm()
        formV = ViaggioForm()
        return render(request, 'fatture/clienti.html', {'formC': formC, 'formV': formV, 'clienti': clienti_list, 'viaggi': viaggi_list})
```

The FormC works fine, only the formV has this problem.

**EDIT**

As Erny's comment recommends, here is the form in the template:

```
<div id="viaggio{{ cliente.id }}" style="display: none; width: 100%; background-color: #f1f1f1; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;">
    <form id="viaggio-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Data viaggio</label>
        {{ formV.data_viaggio }}
        <label>Ddt:</label>
        {{ formV.ddt }}
        <label>Prezzo viaggio:</label>
        {{ formV.prezzo_viaggio }}
        <label>Distanza km:</label>
        {{ formV.distanza_km }}
        <label>Mittente:</label>
        {{ formV.mittente }}
        <script>
            $("#id_mittente").attr("id", "mittente{{ cliente.id }}");
            $("#mittente{{ cliente.id }}").addClass("mittente{{ cliente.id }}")
        </script>
        <p></p>
        <div style="display: none">
            {{ formV.cliente }}
            <script>
                $("#id_cliente").attr("id", "cliente{{ cliente.id }}");
                $('#cliente{{ cliente.id }} option').filter(function(i, e) { return $(e).text() == "{{cliente.nome}}"}).prop('selected', true)
            </script>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="Aggiungi_Viaggio">Aggiungi Viaggio</button>
   </form>
   <button id="chiudi-form-{{ cliente.id }}">Chiudi</button>
</div>
```

And the form:

```
class ViaggioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Viaggio
        fields = ['data_viaggio','distanza_km','ddt','prezzo_viaggio','cliente','mittente']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        numero = kwargs.pop('numero', None)
        if numero == 1:
            self.fields['cliente'].initial = Cliente.objects.get(nome='Inalca')
            self.fields['cliente'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['cliente'].required = False
        else:
            self.fields['cliente'].queryset = Cliente.objects.all().exclude(nome='Inalca')
```

**EDIT 2**

I've changed the form like this and now it works (I deleted the constructor):

```
class ViaggioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Viaggio
        fields = ['data_viaggio','distanza_km','ddt','prezzo_viaggio','cliente','mittente']
```

Why the constructor was a problem?

Comment: Could you provide more info (nodel and form)? It seems that the distanza_km model field is mandatory, but the form does not include this field or does not contain any value.

Comment: I think the problem is in the template, because in the formC I use "{{ form.as_p }}", in the formV I use "{{ form.field_name }}" for every field of the form.

Comment: Ok, i tried to change the code using only {{ form.as_p }} and nothing happened, same as before...

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor the super function is wrong. I changed with the correct form:

```
super(ViaggioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```